# Diferenciar Markers do react-native-maps que possuem a mesma coordenadas

Tags: react-native, maps, maps-javascript-api

estou montando um mapa que desenherá vários marcadores( Marker). Porém, é possível que alguns marcadores possuam as mesmas coordenadas.

Testando o aplicativo, percebi que marcadores que possuem a mesma coordenadas estão sendo sobrescritos.

```
Ex: 
coord1 : latitute: 10 , longitude:20
coord2 : latitude: 10 , longintude:20
coord3 : latitude: 40 , longitude:50
```

No mapa só ficaram visíveis os marcadores de coord2 e coord3. Pois, coord1 foi sobrescrito pelo coord2.
Alguém conhece alguma alternativa para tratar este problema?

Answer (score 0):

Acabei dando uma solução para ajustar o marker. Desloquei o marker sobreposto 0.001 de latitude e longitude.